# Eclipse c++ Console and Problems codeset symbols

Tags: eclipse, visual-c++, encoding, eclipse-cdt

When I trying to build c++ project in Eclipse I retrieving strange symbols in Problems and Console windows. There something like:

```
./src/main.cxx(15) : error C2871: ocilib: Їа®бва ­бвў® Ё¬­ б в ЄЁ¬ Ё¬­¬ ­ бгйбвўгв
./src/main.cxx(39) : error C2653: Environment: ­ пў«пвбп Ё¬­¬ Є« бб  Ё«Ё Їа®бва ­бвў  Ё¬­
./src/main.cxx(39) : error C3861: Initialize: Ё¤­вЁдЁЄ в®а ­ ­ ©¤­
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.EXE" : возвращенный код "0x2"
Stop.

BUILD FAILED
```

Is anyone meets this situation? How you figured up this?

Comment: The _Console_ view uses the encoding specified in the launch configuration in the _Common_ tab (which is by default die encoding of the project folder).

Comment: @howlger I cannot find it.
Can you write please how to get it or change it?

Comment: _Run > Run Configurations..._ (or press Ctrl while hitting the run button or menu item).

Comment: @howlger There is no special Configurations. All default.
I worked only with Releases. Just building exe files and took them into other program as utilities. But now something goes wrong and what wrong is unrecognazible. There strange symbols.

Comment: I see, your question is about building, not running/debugging. I guess it's either something in the C/C++ project build settings (_Project > Properties: C/C++ Build_) or the project text file encoding (_Project > Properties: Resource_). Maybe a Eclipse CDT expert can help (`eclipse-cdt` tag added).

Comment: @howlger Thanks for correcting question, will be waiting for help)